# Select row with timestamp nearest to, but not later than, now

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.4, I am trying to select a single row from from a table that contains data nearest to, but not before, the current system time. The `datetime` colum is a `timestamp without time zone` data type, and the data is in the same timezone as the server. The table structure is:

```
uid |      datetime       |    date    | day |   time   | predictionft | predictioncm | highlow 
-----+---------------------+------------+-----+----------+--------------+--------------+---------
  1 | 2015-12-31 03:21:00 | 2015/12/31 | Thu | 03:21 AM |          5.3 |          162 | H
  2 | 2015-12-31 09:24:00 | 2015/12/31 | Thu | 09:24 AM |          2.4 |           73 | L
  3 | 2015-12-31 14:33:00 | 2015/12/31 | Thu | 02:33 PM |          4.4 |          134 | H
  4 | 2015-12-31 21:04:00 | 2015/12/31 | Thu | 09:04 PM |          1.1 |           34 | L
```

Query speed is not a worry since the table contains ~1500 rows.

For clarity, if the current server time was `2015-12-31 14:00:00`, the row returned should be `3` rather than `2`.

EDIT:
The solution, based on the accepted answer below, was:

```
select * 
from myTable
where datetime =
(select min(datetime)
from myTable 
where datetime > now());
```

EDIT 2: Clarified question.

Comment: nearest for both up and down? I mean if there was a column with say `2015-12-31 13:59:00` it would be selected?

Comment: Jorge - no, in all cases the query should select the row in the future or exactly equal to the current time.

Comment: you say `prior to` , `no later` than in the question. but `after` in this comment. please correct the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea follows.  You can adjust it for postgresql.

```
select fields
from yourTable
where datetimeField = 
(select min(datetimeField)
from yourTable
where datetimeField > current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this. This will be faster. But it wont make much difference if you have few rows.

```
select * from table1
where datetime >= current_timestamp
order by datetime
limit 1
```

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77091/11)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Another approach other than the answers given is to use a window function `first_value`

```
select id, first_value(dt) over (order by dt)
  from test
 where dt >= current_timestamp
 limit 1
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0031c/12